# Why is UTM date shown instead of locale date with Date()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I am facing an small issue with the current date while appending it to json payload. I would like to add the local current data to a json payload, to do so, I am making use of  the commnad

```js
var d = new Date (new Date().getTime()).toLocaleString({ timeZone: 'Europe/Berlin' })
document.write(d);
```

Which returns

> "Date":"9/1/2016, 9:26:34 AM"

However if I run the command `date` on my terminal, it does prompt

```
$ date
Thu  1 Sep 11:27:38 CEST 2016
```

It seems that the first command is not using CEST and instead uses UTC/GMT time therefore I get the two hours offset, why is this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *toLocaleString* is entirely implementation dependent and means that different implementations will generate different strings. If you want a specific format, use a library or write your own function to do so.

Comment: Then, is there no a built-in function to convert my UTC time to CEST ?

Comment: No. Date objects are just a time value that is an offset from the epoch, that's it. Time zone information comes from the host, it's used when creating the time value and when generating values for year, month, day, etc. from that time value. If you set the host to CEST (which is likely impractical) then the plain Date methods (those without "UTC" in them) will return values for that time zone. Or use a library that does time zone transformations (or write it yourself, but I'd suggest a library).

Comment: BTW, for me *toLocaleString* returns a value like "6 September 2016 at 08:40:54 AEST" in Safari, "06/09/2016, 8:40:54 am" in Firefox and "9/6/2016, 8:40:54 AM" in Chrome. It's generally recommended to use UTC everywhere so all dates and times are directly comparable and only convert to "local" for presentation. So use *toISOString* instead.